# what does sql MAX() returns if it looks at 2 equal values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

i've been looking around but could find an answer to this, let's say i have a table with 2 columns

```
something   Price
a             20
b             20
c             10
```

and i want do

```
select MAX(Price) from table
```

seeing as the max price is 20 and there are 2 of them will the MAX command return me both(a and b) or just one, and if just one, why?

Comment: neither `a` nor `b` will be in the result set, you've not included the `something` column in your query

Comment: You could try your query and see the result

Comment: true, my bad what i meant was if it would give me the     20    2 times

Comment: In that case, no, it will only give you one result - thats what aggregation does!

Comment: Please google and learn about the MAX() function in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

If you want both then use `TOP N with ties` and `Order by` instead of `Max` aggregate try this

```
select Top 1 with ties Price from table
order by Price desc
```

`Max` aggregate will return only one row as you don't have `group by`. Also I don't think `Group by` will work for you

Comment: thank you, y i only want one value to be returned, just want's sure of what would happen if i had equal values on 2 rows

Comment: Yes it will return all the max value rows when there is a tie. That's the reason behind `top N with ties`

Answer (score 4):

"Max" is a aggregate function and therefore isn't returning a specific row.  Max(Price) will return the Max number of the Price column which is 20.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx